# How to handle non-blocking functions all reliant on a single callback class?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm working on an Android app that uses BLE. The android device plays the role of the client, and implements the BluetoothGattCallback class.

At present, the code looks like this:

```
  override fun onDescriptorWrite(
        gatt: BluetoothGatt?,
        descriptor: BluetoothGattDescriptor?,
        status: Int
    ) {
        val gattService = gatt?.getService(SERVICE_UUID)
        val timeC = gattService?.getCharacteristic(TIME_UUID)

        if (timeC != null)
        {
            var unixTime = (Calendar.getInstance().timeInMillis/1000)
            val tz = TimeZone.getDefault() as TimeZone
            unixTime += (tz.getOffset(unixTime)/1000)

            val utString = unixTime.toString()
            gatt.writeCharacteristic(timeC,  utString.toByteArray(), BluetoothGattCharacteristic.WRITE_TYPE_DEFAULT)
            Log.i("Time", "Set")
        }

        connected = true
        super.onDescriptorWrite(gatt, descriptor, status)
    }
    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    override fun onCharacteristicChanged(
        gatt: BluetoothGatt,
        characteristic: BluetoothGattCharacteristic,
        value: ByteArray
    ) {
        Log.i("C Change", value.decodeToString())
        super.onCharacteristicChanged(gatt, characteristic, value)
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    override fun onConnectionStateChange(gatt: BluetoothGatt?, status: Int, newState: Int) {

        connected = if(newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
            Log.i("Device status", "Connected!")
            //discover services
            //the discover services callback will set connected to true.
            gatt?.discoverServices()
            false
        } else {
            Log.i("Device status", "Disconnected!")
            false
        }

        super.onConnectionStateChange(gatt, status, newState)
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU)
    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    override fun onServicesDiscovered(gatt: BluetoothGatt?, status: Int) {
        Log.i("Services", "Discovered!")
        val gattService = gatt?.getService(SERVICE_UUID)

        val ackC = gattService?.getCharacteristic(ACK_UUID)

        if(ackC != null)
        {
            gatt.setCharacteristicNotification(ackC, true)
            val descriptor: BluetoothGattDescriptor = ackC.getDescriptor(CHARACTERISTIC_UPDATE_NOTIFICATION_DESCRIPTOR_UUID)

            gatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor, BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE)
        }

        super.onServicesDiscovered(gatt, status)
    }
```

Ideally, the code in the onDescriptorChanged callback would be called inside of the onServiceDiscovered callback. However, as I am required to wait until onDescriptorChanged is called to call writeCharacteristic, I've moved it as such.

This seems a bit clunky to me, and I'm not sure if it's the right way to go about it, even though it does work.